# javac works on its own but doesn't work with scons

Tags: java, windows, scons

From the command line, I can do this and get expected output

```
    c:\Users\SomeUser\SomePath\sandbox> javac Sandbox.java
```

If I use the SConstruct in conjunction with scons, in the same location, I get

```
    c:\Users\SomeUser\SomePath\sandbox> scons

    scons: done reading SConscript files.
    scons: Building targets ...
    javac -d classes -sourcepath . Sandbox.java
    'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    scons: *** [classes\Sandbox.class] Error 1
    scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Where is your java installed?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the answer to #1 of our "most frequently asked" FAQs at http://scons.org/faq.html could help you out. By default, SCons doesn't import the variables like `$PATH` from the surrounding shell environment. You have to pull in your `$PATH` for properly detecting the `javac` executable explicitly...check the mentioned FAQ entry for a more detailed discussion about why things are as they are, and how to provide the required `$PATH` definitions to your build environments.

Comment: That's weird, I never had to do that with my C/C++ and python apps.